# simulating an incoming sms in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, sms, simulation

I am making a Windows phone application in C# using Visual Studio 2013. I want to simulate an incoming SMS to my mobile phone/emulator. I want 100 messages per second.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: To do a load test on my application.

Comment: How does receiving an SMS 'load test' your app? a WP8 app is not aware of incoming SMSs, nor does it have access to them.